# Is there a way to stop IE from hanging when opening saved pages short of turning off the phishing filter?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, freeze, internet-explorer-10

A quick web search turned up the improbable fix of turning off one's IE phishing filter (http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/ie7-page-save-mht-regularly-hangs-save-webpage-dialog-help-118769041.html?page=2) to get IE to quickly open saved web pages.

Does anyone know a solution that doesn't require turning off the phishing filter?

I'm running IE10 on Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Saving files as MHTs doesn't help.

Comment: That workaround seems to be for IE7 hanging while saving pages, whereas in your case it's hanging while opening them. Does turning off the phishing filter even help you? Which version of IE/Windows are you using? I've often found that pages have lots of JS running on load and IE hangs while trying to either run these scripts or attempting to access/download linked resources. After it was successful or timed out the actual textual content loaded quickly of course. Editing the HTML source and deleting useless scripts helps. Plus do you *have* to save as HTML or can you save text+images as a doc?

Comment: Yes, it helps me. I really don't want to launch yet another program just to save the contents of a web page. I've edited the question to answer the main body of your comment.

Comment: Are you saving only the HTML page, or the complete page with images? Have you tried saving as a single MHT yet?

Comment: I'm saving the whole document with images. Yes.